# Images in Right Folder But Sometimes Not Rendering

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

```
FlowRouter.route '/',
    name: 'Landing'
    action: ->
        BlazeLayout.render 'MainLayout', main: 'landing'
FlowRouter.route '/aesthetics-test/intro',
    name: 'aesthetics-testintro'
    action: ->
        BlazeLayout.render 'MainLayout', main: 'aesTest', aesMain: 'aesIntro'
MainLayout.tpl.jade ~~~
main
  +navBar
  +Template.dynamic(template=main)
```

On Landing all images render. Routing through FlowRouter to aesthetics-testintro everything renders (keeping MainLayout template). Manually reloading the page, the favicon and an img in the navBar stop working even though they show up in console inspect and their paths are correct. Anybody know what's going on?

To see this you can go to http://www.gametree.me/
If you go there, click explore, then refresh the page the image in the nav bar breaks. Let me know any other code you'd like to see.

Comment: You should maybe include any javascript that your working with. I don't really have any idea how that would affect your situation but it might. Also, do the images not show up at all and there is nothing in the empty space they would take up or does a broken image icon appear?

Comment: This is the website: http://www.gametree.me/
If you go there, click explore, then refresh the page the image on the Email Subscription breaks. Let me know any other code you'd like to see.